# Docker managing Java minor versions

Tags: java, docker, upgrade

I've a docker container with an official Java alpine base image. What we need is upgrade Java to its last minor version, but I don't find the best way to do it.

What I mind about best way for me will be take an alpine based image with the last minor version but there is not available in all Java version, for example for version 8 there is an alpine version with 8u171 but to move to 8u181 I must to take a bigger one (8_slim), for Java 7 there is not an official docker image so the last one available is 7u181 and not the 7u191.

So there could be a way to upgrade also manually when the docker image is built?

Comment: Well the openjdk8 alpine image uses the apk package manager to install the `openjdk8` apk package. According to this search: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openjdk8&branch=edge the latest available alpine package is still at 171. There is not much that can be done to upgrade unless you're willing to build the latest IcedTea project on Alpine yourself.

Comment: FWIW I wound up building my own Alpine+Java base image for exactly this reason.  In principle you can use `apk` to install the newer version on the existing image, but the way Docker works you wind up carrying both JVMs around and the image is twice the size, which isn’t what you want.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I've not found the way to install the Java 8u181 to Alpine image with Java version 8u171. How could I install by `apk` the Java 8u181 to the official image `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`? Which work with 8u171.
Thanks